# Increasing the quantity of a single item in the shop cart also increase the quantity of other items

Tags: angular, typescript

Whenever I try to increase the quantity of an item , it also increase the quantity of other items in the shop. This appears visually when I click the button to toggle the quantity, the other items are also updated with the current quantity of what I updated. Each item has its own unique id, so I try to pass the id into the increaseItemQty function then you use a for lop to iterate over each item in the item array but that does not work. Can someone please assist?

> 

HTML

```
    <p><strong>Price:</strong> ${{item.Cost * quantity}}</p>

    {{quantity}}

    <button mat-icon-button (click)="increaseItemQty(id)">
      <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

> Typescript

```
 quantity : any = 1;
 increaseItemQty(id: any) {
  this.itemService.getAllItems()
     .subscribe(res => {
        this.itemList = res;
         this.itemList.find((i: { id: any; }) => id === id,
          this.quantity+=1)  
  })
 }
```

Comment: Hello,
Could you share your code on https://stackblitz.com/

The first, what you need to do moving Subscription from increaseItemQty to OnInit method.
The second iId shpild look like i.Id

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fwdqwv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts @NikitaBardakov This is a very condensed version of the original code since those snippets rely on a backend.

Comment: The "quantity" should be or an array or a property of the "item". You can use only one variable. So I suggest your items was on the way {id:..,name:...,description,..., **quantity:0**}. In this way you use `{{item.Cost * item.quantity}}`